# Angular JS Array Parsing

Tags: angularjs

So I am in the very beginning stages of making an interactive game with Angular JS. I have been stumped for the past two days on how I would go about only logging the wrong guesses to the screen(instead of logging every guess typed in). My goal is to ultimately have a max wrong guess amount of 10, then the user loses. I am just stumped at how I would do this. New to Angular, but can't figure it out in plain JS either. Any help or hints would be much appreciated.

```js
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var answerArray = ["linux","macintosh","windows"];
  var answer = answerArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * answerArray.length)];
  $scope.answer = answer;
  $scope.userGuesses = [];
  $scope.wrongGuesses = [];
  $scope.guessTracker = 0;

  $scope.guessCheck = function(){
    if($scope.userGuesses.indexOf($scope.guess) === -1){
      $scope.userGuesses.push($scope.guess);
    }
    $scope.guess = "";
  };

  $scope.letterDisplay = function(){
    var chars = $scope.answer.split("");

    _.each(chars, function(val, index){
      if( $scope.userGuesses.indexOf(val) === -1){
        chars[index] = "_";
      }
    });
    return chars;
  };
}]);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://jashkenas.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="hangMan">

    <div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">
      <div class="row text-center">
          <h1>Save Bernie</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div id="messageDisplay">
            <span ng-repeat="char in letterDisplay() track by $index">
              {{char}}
            </span>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Drawing -->
      <div id="mainContent" class="row rowspacing">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div id="drawingWrapper">
            <div id="pole"></div>
            <div id="poleExtension"></div>
            <div id="rope"></div>
            <div id="torso"></div>
            <div id="head"></div>
            <div id="leftArm"></div>
            <div id="rightArm"></div>
            <div id="leftLeg"></div>
            <div id="rightLeg"></div>
            <div id="hillary"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <!-- Controls -->
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
          <div id="userSubmit">
            <form ng-submit="guessCheck()">
              <input type="text" name="guess" ng-model="guess" required><button>Guess</button>
            </form>
             <div id="guessDisplay" ng-repeat="character in userGuesses track by $index">
              {{character}}
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script src='/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script>var app = angular.module("hangMan", []);</script>
    <script src='/js/MainController.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's talk about making a changes to your current code. You can improve performance and make it easier to search for unique user guesses by using a JS object instead of an array. You weren't checking if the guess was correct in the guessCheck function. This is where you can push the wrong guesses to the wrongGuesses array. That is mostly all that needs to be done at the controller. In the HTML template you can use various ng directives such as ng-show, ng-click, etc. to provide the various presentation updates based on the state of the game.

```js
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var answerArray = ["linux","macintosh","windows"];
  var answer = answerArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * answerArray.length)];
  $scope.answer = answer;
  $scope.userGuesses = {};
  $scope.wrongGuesses = [];

  $scope.guessCheck = function() {
    if(!$scope.userGuesses.hasOwnProperty($scope.guess)){
      var isCorrectGuess = ~$scope.answer.indexOf($scope.guess);
      if (!isCorrectGuess)
        $scope.wrongGuesses.push($scope.guess);
      $scope.userGuesses[$scope.guess] = "true";
    }
    $scope.guess = "";
  };

  $scope.letterDisplay = function(){
    var chars = $scope.answer.split("");

    _.each(chars, function(val, index){
      if(!$scope.userGuesses.hasOwnProperty(val)){
        chars[index] = "_";
      }
    });
    return chars;
  };
}]);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://jashkenas.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="hangMan">

    <div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">
      <div class="row text-center">
          <h1>Save Bernie <span ng-show="wrongGuesses.length===10">(Game OVER!)</span></h1>
      </div>

      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div id="messageDisplay">
            <span ng-repeat="char in letterDisplay() track by $index">
              {{char}}
            </span>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Drawing -->
      <div id="mainContent" class="row rowspacing">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div id="drawingWrapper">
            <div id="pole"></div>
            <div id="poleExtension"></div>
            <div id="rope"></div>
            <div id="torso"></div>
            <div id="head"></div>
            <div id="leftArm"></div>
            <div id="rightArm"></div>
            <div id="leftLeg"></div>
            <div id="rightLeg"></div>
            <div id="hillary"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <!-- Controls -->
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
          <div id="userSubmit">
            <form ng-submit="guessCheck()">
              <input type="text" name="guess" ng-model="guess" required maxlength="1"><button ng-show="wrongGuesses.length < 10">Guess</button><button ng-show="wrongGuesses.length===10" ng-click="wrongGuesses = []">Reset</button> Wrong Guesses: {{wrongGuesses.length}}
            </form>
             <div id="guessDisplay" ng-repeat="(character,value) in userGuesses track by $index">
              {{character}}
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script src='/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script>var app = angular.module("hangMan", []);</script>
    <script src='/js/MainController.js'></script>
```

**Update**: I forgot to mention that you should eventually create a function for the reset button that should reset the userGuesses object, wrongGuesses array, and reset the answer or fetch a new answer. Currently only the wrongGuesses array is being reset.

Comment: No problem, answer was much appreciated.

Comment: Ideally I don't want to use underscore.js any quick recommendations on what I could implement instead of that _.each function?

Answer (score 1):

explanations in comments. I've also set the maxlength of input textbox to 1. Replaced most conditions to underscore functions, since you're just using it as well, why not use for all?

```js
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var answerArray = ["linux","macintosh","windows"];
  var answer = answerArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * answerArray.length)];

  $scope.answer = answer;
  $scope.userGuesses = [];
  $scope.wrongGuesses = [];
  $scope.guessTracker = 0;  //unused

  $scope.guessCheck = function(){
    // if $scope.guess still doesn't exists on $scope.userGuesses, push it
    if(!_.contains($scope.userGuesses, $scope.guess)){
      // convert $scope.answer into array
      var chars = $scope.answer.split("");

      $scope.userGuesses.push($scope.guess);

      // if $scope.guess is not found on chars array, add it to wrongGuesses
      if(!_.contains(chars, $scope.guess)) {
         $scope.wrongGuesses.push($scope.guess);
      }

      // pop-up alert if wrong guesses reaches 10 or more
      if(_.size($scope.wrongGuesses) >= 10) {
         alert("gameover");
      }
    }
    $scope.guess = "";
  };

  $scope.letterDisplay = function(){
    var chars = $scope.answer.split("");

    _.each(chars, function(val, index){
      // used _.contains instead of .indexOf because why not?
      if(!_.contains($scope.userGuesses, val)){
        chars[index] = "_";
      }
    });
    return chars;
  };

}]);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://jashkenas.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="hangMan">

    <div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">
      <div class="row text-center">
          <h1>Save Bernie</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div id="messageDisplay">
            <span ng-repeat="char in letterDisplay() track by $index">
              {{char}}
            </span>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Drawing -->
      <div id="mainContent" class="row rowspacing">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div id="drawingWrapper">
            <div id="pole"></div>
            <div id="poleExtension"></div>
            <div id="rope"></div>
            <div id="torso"></div>
            <div id="head"></div>
            <div id="leftArm"></div>
            <div id="rightArm"></div>
            <div id="leftLeg"></div>
            <div id="rightLeg"></div>
            <div id="hillary"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <!-- Controls -->
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
          <div id="userSubmit">
            <form ng-submit="guessCheck()">
              <input type="text" name="guess" ng-model="guess" maxlength="1" required><button>Guess</button>
            </form>
             <div id="guessDisplay" ng-repeat="character in wrongGuesses track by $index">
              {{character}}
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script src='/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script>var app = angular.module("hangMan", []);</script>
    <script src='/js/MainController.js'></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. Much appreciated!